# Can't display string data values from json data with ckeditor

Tags: jquery, json, yii, ckeditor

I would like send data json on textfield.

```
echo CJSON::encode(array(
      'status'=>true,
      'name'=>$model=>NAME,
      'place'=>$model=>PLACE,
      'description'=>$model->DESCRIPTION
));
```

I am trying to display the string on the form input and textarea from json in this way

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl(controller/action); ?>',
  data: 'reff=reff',
  success: function(data) {
    var values=jQuery.parseJSON(data);
    if(values.status==true) {
      $('#name').val(values.name); // form input text
      $('#place').val(values.place); // form input text
      $('#description').val(values.description); // textarea
    } else {
       alert("errors");
    }
  }
});
```

and that success. However, when I use ckeditor, string can't display. I have change code to be `CKEDITOR.instances.description.getData(values.description);` 
But it not work...

Comment: typo `$model=>NAME` & `$model=>PLACE`

Comment: you want to setdata to ckeditor or get data from ckeditor?

Comment: I want to get data from json and put it in ckeditor .. I've tried to use this $('#description').val(object.description); ... this script work in textarea, but not work in ckeditor